# Dynamic size canvas with Scroll bars

Tags: wpf, canvas, autosize

I am developing a simple WPF application without any auto layout. The goal is when a user clicks (mouse down) a element (say textBlock) will appear at the location of the mouse click. For this I am using canvas panel embedded in a Grid of 1 row, 1 column and scrollviewer (visible). The issues are:
1. when the application window is resized the scroll viewers do not become active.
2. I want the ability to auto grow the canvas with mouse drag. Something like in MS-Excel when user drags the mouse horizontally/vertically the canvas should grow.

I have searched net a lot to figure this out and am unable to get an answer. Any help in this regard would be great.
Thanks a bunch in advance.

-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I after asking this question I figured it out how to have freeform layout and autosize. Here is a sample XAML if anyone needs it or has better suggestion to improve this:

```
        <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" Fill="Red"/>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

        <!-- Creating a grid with one row and one column"-->
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ServerLiistCanvasScrollViewer" 
                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"                         
                      Height="Auto" Width="Auto"
                    Grid.Column="2" >

            <Grid x:Name="drawingGrid" Grid.Column="2" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  Background="Pink"
                  MouseDown="handleCanvasMouseDown">
            </Grid>        
        </ScrollViewer>


    </Grid>
```